# What does "EXCEPT distinct select * " in SQL language mean?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am following a tutorial on Qwiklabs on Bigquery and financial fraud detection and came across a query, below, that I am failing to understand

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE finance.fraud_data_model AS
SELECT
*
FROM finance.fraud_data_sample  
EXCEPT distinct select * from finance.fraud_data_test
```

I am trying to understand what is being retrieved or ignored from the `finance.fraud_data_test` table
or what is the main `finance.fraud_data_model` made up of when it comes to the two other tables?

Comment: It's there in the documentation: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#except

Comment: Not mentioned in any of the answers yet is that `EXCEPT DISTINCT` is as opposed to `EXCEPT ALL`

Comment: An good explanation for `EXCEPT ALL` (https://modern-sql.com/caniuse/except-all) and `EXCEPT DISTINCT` (https://modern-sql.com/caniuse/except-distinct)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The SQL EXCEPT statement is used to filter records based on the intersection of records returned via two SELECT statements.

The records that are common between the two tables are filtered from the table on the left side of the SQL EXCEPT statement and the remaining records are returned.

```
SELECT * FROM finance.fraud_data_sample  
EXCEPT distinct select * from finance.fraud_data_test
```

In your case, the query returns every record in `finance.fraud_data_sample`
that are not present in the unique list obtained from`finance.fraud_data_test`

Answer (score 4):

`EXCEPT` is a set operation, such as `UNION` and `INTERSECT`.

It returns all rows in the first table that do not have an exact match in the second, and also removes any duplicates.  Because it is using `SELECT *`, the assumption is that the two tables have the same columns in the same order.

Answer (score 0):

The EXCEPT keyword is used as an excluding filter for the query. In this case, it will return the rows from fraud_data_sample that are *not* in fraud_data_test.